# Multiple instances of Date Picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

How can i able to use multiple instances of date picker? One date picker is working but the next instance of date picker is invoking the same popup, how to proceed?
Can anyone give me your Email Id...I will mail you the whole code...then you will be able to get the whole idea in better way

http://jsfiddle.net/premseoul/BjDYP/

Whole set of codes are available at the link in a Zip ..please download the zip.....
http://www.4shared.com/file/ZQy2A3DU/DateTime.html

Comment: datepicker works with multiple instances, how are you calling it? POST YOUR CODE!

Comment: and which version of jQueryUI are you using?  There were fixes a short while back to help out the multiple-instance case.

Comment: How can able to show the whole source code?

Comment: @Khez Can you please give me your Email iD or can you suggest me a way so that i can able to share codes with you......

Comment: Popular solutions include: http://jsfiddle.net/, http://pastebin.com/, http://jsbin.com/. Choose your weapon ... FIGHT!

Comment: @ All Code is at http://jsfiddle.net/premseoul/BjDYP/

Comment: You aren't using the [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) plugin it seems.

Comment: I am using the datepicker plugin..the code of plugin_time is the java script at http://jsfiddle.net/zalun/NF2jz/

Comment: I have uploaded the whole set of files at http://www.4shared.com/file/ZQy2A3DU/DateTime.html

Comment: @Khez if possible please create multiple instance of date picker and mail me/or upload at $shared.com............

Comment: Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4Aqz/) by @Calum, who posted just bellow.

Comment: Still don't really understand what you want. Are you looking to get TWO versions of the calendar pop up when you click on a SINGLE input? Consider creating a new question which is better worded.

Comment: @Calum I would like say that I dont need Two version of Calender Pop up on single input/click....but I wanted two or more Instances of datepicker...............I have got some solutions but it will be highly appreciable if you have a look onn the 4shared.com/file/ZQy2A3DU/DateTime.html  Because i have used this datepicker at some pages...so i need to change my code in some way.....PLease if possible download the file and open the HTML and try to solve my Query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/d4Aqz/

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
$( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
```

Comment: `$( "#datepicker, #datepicker2, #datepicker3, ..." ).datepicker();`

Comment: can you give me your email id so that i will be able to show you the whole code...............

Comment: @Calum can you please assist me by giving your email id or i will upload it on www.4shared.com?

Comment: @Calum Can you please share the complete code,i.e.the whole javascript code.it will be really helpful......The Demo is Exactly the solution of my problem

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onload = function(){
    new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"inputField1",
        dateFormat:"%Y-%m-%d"
        /*selectedDate:{                This is an example of what the full configuration offers.
            day:5,                      For full documentation about these settings please see the full version of the code.
            month:9,
            year:2006
        },
        yearsRange:[1978,2020],
        limitToToday:false,
        cellColorScheme:"beige",
        dateFormat:"%Y-%M-%d",
        imgPath:"img/",
        weekStartDay:1*/
    });
};
```

but the function is called this way

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what you mean. But if you have multiple datepicker you must use `class`.

```
<script>
        $(function() {
                        $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
                        });
</script>


<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                        <td  width="300">Problem Date</td>
                                        <td width="10">:</td>
                                        <td width="150" align="left">
                                                <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="prob_date" class="datepicker">
                                        </td>
                                </tr>

                                 <tr>
                                        <td  width="300">Eff. Date</td>
                                        <td width="10">:</td>
                                        <td width="150" align="left">
                                                <input type="text" id="datepick" name="eff_date" class="datepicker">
                                        </td>
                                </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Really? I've called them by ID before and instantiated them with different preset dates and other parameters where there are multiple pickers on the one page.

Comment: @niggles: ya..i work with that.i have two datepickers in my form and it works normally.

Comment: @klox Ya ya thats fine but i can able to do that......How can i able to share the whole code with you?

Comment: @prem: just do like khez comment use the popular sites for post the whole your code.then post your linked code from that site.

Comment: I want to use Multiple instances of time/date picker on the same page

Comment: @klox i have uplaoaded the file at http://www.4shared.com/file/ZQy2A3DU/DateTime.html